# Consulta tira un error por columna ambigua

Tags: postgresql

Buenos días estoy realizando una consulta en postgress y arroja un error:

> "ERROR:  la referencia a la columna «num_solicitud» es ambigua  LINE
>   4: WHERE num_solicitud in (3,6,9);",

```
select * from area
inner join empleado on area.num_solicitud = empleado.num_solicitud
inner join bien on area.num_solicitud = bien.num_solicitud
WHERE num_solicitud in (3,6,9);
```

Comment: Gracias me ayudaste mucho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que te esta pasando es que ese campo tiene el mismo nombre en dos o más tablas de la consulta. 
Tienes que especificar de que tabla es el campo num_solicitud.

```
select * from area
inner join empleado on area.num_solicitud = empleado.num_solicitud
inner join bien on area.num_solicitud = bien.num_solicitud
WHERE tabla.num_solicitud in (3,6,9);
```

A mayores te aconsejaría añadir un alias a tus tablas, para que sea más fácil referenciarlas.

```
select * from area a
inner join empleado emp on a.num_solicitud = emp.num_solicitud
inner join bien b on a.num_solicitud = b.num_solicitud
```

Un saludo.

Comment: la respuesta esta cada vez mejor.. pero si vas a usar un alias, aprovecha y usalo en todos lados ;) a.num_solicitud = emp.num_solicitud